# to do list - excel function search

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to generate a few interconnected sheets in excel. What I want is a function that will allow me to create an every changing to do list.

e.g. if the value in C1 (sheet 1) = F, then print the value from A1 (sheet1) in A1 (sheet2)

any suggestions appreciated

Comment: You need to be slightly clearer with your question. VLOOKUPs would seemingly be the right function to use, but this depends on what exactly you are trying to do and how your sheets are set up.

Comment: Basically, I have a seet with some data in Name, Location, Sent. I want to be able to enter a value in the Sent column e.g. the letter F and this result in the value for Name being printed in another sheet. (this is a simplified example the dataset is huge, I thought of Vlookup but it doesnt quite meet my needs)

Comment: Once i have the inital column pasted in, I can setup the rest of the sheet with Vlookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following code into A1 of Sheet2. If C1 of Sheet1 is not equal to F, then the cell will remain blank

```
=IF(Sheet1!C1="F",Sheet1!A1,"")
```

Comment: Thats what I was looking for! I didnt think of IF. Is there a way to expand this so that if there is an F at any location in the C column, the corresponding value from the A column would be copied across?

Comment: If you copy this formula down in Sheet2, then it will replace C1 with C2, A1 with A2 etc. Is that what you are after, or would you like A1 on Sheet2 to be changed if F appear anywhere in column C and not only in C1?

Comment: Anywhere in the column

Comment: Try =IF(Sheet1!C:C="F", Sheet1!A1,"")

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, Change to A:A may be a fix. I will trial it.